# Which encodings can I use for single quotes in sitemaps?

Tags: xml, escaping, sitemap

[The XML schema for the sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping) says that single quotes in URLs have to be escaped to `&apos;`. [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/html-escaping.html) "double-stash" (`{{...}}`) escapes single quotes into `&#x27;`.

Unfortunately, I can't find any information out there stating whether this difference is of relevance or if I can use either encoding.

Can anyone tell me if it matters for sitemaps if I use the handlebars version (`&#x27;`)?

Answer (score 0):

Provisional answer:

I have tried [an online validation service](https://freetools.webmasterworld.com/tools/site-validator/) using this dummy-sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/index.html&amp;q=&apos;name&#x27;</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

So at least *if that service's validation is correct*, it doesn't seem to matter which encoding you use for single quotes and thus using the handlebars escaping mechanism should be suifficient for preparing URLs for sitemaps.